# Renaming open files in sublime text 2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, rename

I am trying to rename open files in sublime text 2. In **version 2.0.1 Build 2217**, you could rename by pressing `f2` or by `opening the command palette by pressing` **Ctrl + Shift + P** `and entering rename`. However in the latest version of sublime text 2 which is **2.0.2 Build 2221** when you try to do the same thing nothing happens. I have also entered the following command in the users key binding file  but again nothing happens.

> { "keys": ["f2"], "command": "rename_path", "args": {"paths":
>   []} }

This happens on both windows & linux. I have tried this on a fresh copy of Sublime Text 2 with no plugins.

Comment: Any clue why this functionality was removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy to your [User keymap](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html#defining-and-overriding-key-bindings)

```
{ "keys": ["shift+f2"], "command": "rename_file", "args": { "paths": ["$file"] } }
```

Create directory/file in your [Packages folder](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory): "...Packages/RenameFile/rename_file.py"

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os
import functools


class RenameFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, paths):
        if paths[0] == "$file":
            paths[0] = self.window.active_view().file_name()
        branch, leaf = os.path.split(paths[0])
        v = self.window.show_input_panel("New Name:", leaf, functools.partial(self.on_done, paths[0], branch), None, None)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(leaf)

        v.sel().clear()
        v.sel().add(sublime.Region(0, len(name)))

    def on_done(self, old, branch, leaf):
        new = os.path.join(branch, leaf)

        try:
            os.rename(old, new)

            v = self.window.find_open_file(old)
            if v:
                v.retarget(new)
        except:
            sublime.status_message("Unable to rename")

    def is_visible(self, paths):
        return len(paths) == 1
```

Comment: That also makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the plugin.

Comment: Great works. However, the keyboard shortcuts does not show up next to **File: Rename** when you type it in the command palette. Is this feature removed in the latest version of sublime text as it did not require any plugins in the previous versions (**2.0.2 Build 2221**).

Comment: This is not a Sublime Text feature.  It is a simple plugin that I found somewhere.  I'm not sure what you used before to rename files, but it seems like you uninstalled it or it is broken.

Comment: great that worked!

Answer (score 8):

Reference: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9534

Another simple way to set up a keyboard shortcut for renaming files:

Install SideBar Enhancements, and set up the shortcut in `Key Bindings - User`:

`{ "keys": ["your shortcut combination"], "command": "side_bar_move" }`

Comment: the reference is just the right kind. No need to install any package or such.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a package for Sublime Text 3:

https://github.com/brianlow/FileRename